# How to run Spotbugs via Maven?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, static-analysis, spotbugs

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 

     <groupId>de.stackoverflow.test</groupId>
     <artifactId>HelloWorld</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>jar</packaging> 
     <name>HelloWorld</name> 

     <dependencies>   
             <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0-RC5</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
     </dependencies>

     <build>        
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
           <groupId>com.github.hazendaz.spotbugs</groupId>
           <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.6</version>
           <dependencies>

           <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
           <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0-RC5</version>
           </dependency>
           </dependencies>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
```

`mvn compile`, `mvn package` and `mvn site` run without any problems. *Build Success.*

The project consists of a single `HelloWorld.java` with some bugs in it.

`mvn site` does not show me any bugs or errors. How do I get SpotBugs to scan my code?

Comment: Why are you defining `src/main/java` as resource directory? and why redefining conventions  ? like source directoy ?

Comment: Good question. It's definitely not necessary. I've updated the sourcecode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [spotbugs-maven-plugin version 3.1.0-RC6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.spotbugs/spotbugs-maven-plugin/3.1.0-RC6), then you can find problem by [`mvn spotbugs:spotbugs`](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/spotbugs-mojo.html). You may refer [official document in readthedocs](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maven.html).

Answer (score 7):

The `spotbugs:check` mojo runs [by default](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html) in the `verify` phase of the [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). This phase is located after `compile` and `package`.

To trigger the spotbugs check, invoke Maven with anything >= `verify`, for instance `mvn verify` or `mvn install`.

You could also attach the plugin to another lifecycle phase, I presume, like this:

```
<execution>
  <id>check</id>
  <phase>test</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>check</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
```

I have not tested that, though.

Answer (score 4):

For spotbugs to run as part of `mvn site` you just need to ensure the plugin is in the `<reporting>` section in your pom.xml:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

The `<reporting>` element is at the same level as the `<build>` element.

I'd also add that a useful convenience method to run spotbugs on a project without adding anything to the pom is:

```
mvn com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:spotbugs
```

Then inspect `target/spotbugsXml.xml`.

Even more convenient sometimes is the gui goal:

```
mvn com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-maven-plugin:gui
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was due to incorrectly migrating from Findbugs - see https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html#for-spotbugs-users.

Also, for testing whether spotbugs is working, you can just run

> mvn spotbugs:check

And see if the target\spotbugsXml.xml file is produced.